# Does Selenium Web driver Support IE6?

Tags: testing, cross-browser, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium test automation. I have been recording test cases in Firefox and exporting the same as JUnit. I invoked the test cases with selenium web driver and run in different browsers. All test cases fail in IE6. But the same cases working fine in IE8 and 9. The issue is related to clicks. Clicks are not working in IE6, both by XPath and CSSpath.

I have tried the following code to invoke a click on same elements but it fails with error:

```
selenium.click("link=Advanced Search");
//selenium.click("xpath=//*[@id='simpleSearch']/a");
        //selenium.click("css=div.cm>form#distributions>div#distributionsTab.bd>div#simpleSearch.mtm>a.mlm");
```

StackTrace:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Session ID: d90dd5dc-7800-4674-ba89-a159a820128b
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=internet explorer, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=6}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.SeleneseCommand.apply(SeleneseCommand.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.Timer.run(Timer.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.execute(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.doCommand(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.click(DefaultSelenium.java:193)
    at com.magicbox.testsuite.MagicBoxTestSuite.MotelTie6(MagicBoxTestSuite.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:21)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:19)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:232)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:223)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:129)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:232)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:223)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Session ID: d90dd5dc-7800-4674-ba89-a159a820128b
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=internet explorer, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=6}]
```

Comment: Why are people still using IE6?

Comment: You aren't using the WebDriver API, you are using the Selenium RC API which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

According do their website [Internet Explorer Driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), they do.

Comment: yes, according to their documentation, it does. But its giving lots of errors while running test cases via selenium web driver.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but you're code doesn't seem like the proper syntax from Selenium WebDriver.